# ObjectDisposedException NSDate when formatting date

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the following method to format a UnixTimestamp to a formatted date and time:

```cs
public string ConvertDateTimeToDeviceShortDateFormat(double unixTimestamp)
{
   using (var dateInNsDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSince1970(unixTimestamp))
   {
        using (var formatter = new NSDateFormatter())
        {
            formatter.TimeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.None;
            formatter.DateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.Short;
            formatter.Locale = NSLocale.CurrentLocale;

            return formatter.ToString(dateInNsDate);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called each second in my Xamarin.Forms app and sometimes it throws ObjectDisposedException when calling this method.

```
Xamarin Exception Stack:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Foundation.NSDate'.
  at ObjCRuntime.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException (System.Object o) <0x101ca8be0 + 0x00038> in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772#0f6f385f46b536c4b979ed569af516e5>:0
  at ObjCRuntime.NativeObjectExtensions.GetNonNullHandle (ObjCRuntime.INativeObject self, System.String argumentName) <0x101ca5d70 + 0x00077> in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772#0f6f385f46b536c4b979ed569af516e5>:0
  at Foundation.NSDateFormatter.ToString (Foundation.NSDate date) <0x101c1f920 + 0x00027> in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772#0f6f385f46b536c4b979ed569af516e5>:0
```

Is there an issue with disposing NSDate on each call?

Comment: there are numerous ways to do this in .NET - is there a reason you're using Obj-C classes?

Comment: It is a platform-specific code because we need to format the date and time according to the device format/setting

Comment: AFAIK the .NET formatters will use the user's device settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the code wasn't thread-safe. I reproduced the error by forcing a multi-thread call.

I ended up using a lock to ensure exclusive access, and that resolved my issue.